# Proving that the tree T contains at most k − 2 nodes of degree three or more.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, trees

Let G = (V, E) be an undirected graph and T a tree in G with k ≥ 2 leaves. Prove that
the tree T contains at most k − 2 nodes of degree three or more.

This is what I have:

k-2 = the number of internal vertices
 = the sum of degrees of internal vertices
k = the number of leaves

The sum of the degrees  is twice the number of edges  in the tree, diminished with the number of leaves k, since their edges are only counted in the degrees of their parents:

= 2 − k

Because the number of edges  in the tree is one less than the number of vertices, we also have:

= k-2 + k − 1

So we can substitute the  in the first equation:

= 2(k-1+k − 1) - k= 3k-6

We then divide s/k-2=3
Would this be the correct way of getting a solution or is it better to use the average degree of a tree formula $\frac{2(n-1)} n$ Where we still get 3?

Comment: Why is the number of internal vertices $k-2$? You could have a tree with 2 leaves and just one vertex of degree $2$, which is an internal vertex, but according to your count there are $2-2=0$ internal vertices.

Comment: I thought  that nodes (k-2) would be the rest without the leaves, though it would still mean that at most there are k-2 so there could be 0?

Comment: But if the answer is correct then it works, no?

Comment: The answer is not correct. I can give a number of counterexamples in which the number of internal vertices is not $k-2$, for example take $T$ to be the tree with one vertex of degree 4 and four leaves. This tree contains exactly one node of degree 3 or more. Furthermore, according to your formula $s=3k-6$, if e.g $k=4$ then the sum of the degrees of internal vertices is 6. But the same tree $T$ with one vertex of degree 4 and four leaves does not satisfy your count.

Comment: So what can I do? How can I solve this correctly?

Comment: Let $p$ be the number of vertices of degree $2$. Then there are $n-p-k$ vertices of degree $3$ or more. What you need to prove is that $n-p-k\leq k-2$. Now we note that $\sum \deg v \geq k + 2p + 3(n-p-k)$. Now we use that $\sum \deg v = 2(n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you!! 2(n−1)≥k+2p+3(n−p−k), 2n-2≥k+2p+3n−3p−3k, k-2≥n-k-p, is this enough?

Comment: Correct, that is precisely what you need.